# Self signed certificate ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for CN==URL

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, openssl

I have generated the self signed certificate with subject alternate names for alias server and IP address. I have imported the certificate into Windows Trusted certificate authorities. Chrome accepts the certificate for URL from SAN but rejects URL stated in Subject.

OpenSSL:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 999 -nodes \
-keyout nginx.key -out nginx.crt  -subj '/CN=www.X.eu' \
-extensions san  \
-config <(echo '[req]'; echo 'distinguished_name=req'; echo '[san]'; echo 'subjectAltName=DNS:X.eu,DNS:re1.X.eu,DNS:10.105.1.11')
```

The certificate:

```
Subject: CN = www.X.eu
Subject Alternative Name:
 DNS Name=sandbox.X.eu 
 DNS Name=re1.X.eu 
 DNS Name=10.105.1.11
```

This URL fails with "This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)."

```
https://www.X.eu/favicon.ico
```

Chrome accept this URL:

```
https://re1.X.eu/favicon.ico
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: That's how it works for all modern browsers.  Add `www.X.eu` to the SAN extension too and it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTPS, the CN field is *not* merged with subjectAltName – rather, it is completely ignored when the SAN extension has any domains in it. So whatever domain you have in the CN you *must* add to SAN as well.

In fact you could even leave out CN from the Subject entirely, as all TLS clients support SAN.

[RFC 2818: HTTP Over TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), section 3.1 "Server Identity":

```
   If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
   be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
   field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used.
```